# Batch file to match partial directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, match

I am trying to write a script to automate a program to run after a file is finished downloading in a particular directory. The issue I have is when the files download they are in their own folder. What I need is for somehow to match just the TV Shows folder and not the actual folder the video is in.

Below is my batch file:

```
(IF /I %2=="G:\TV Shows" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\theRenamer\theRenamer.exe" -fetch))
```

Here is an example.

```
(IF /I "G:\TV Shows\Bates.Motel.S01E10.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264-KiNGS [PublicHD]"=="G:TV Shows" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\theRenamer\theRenamer.exe" -fetch))
```

Obviously it does not run properly, I tried adding in a * for wildcard character and matching sub strings but I could not get either to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't get your question ... please clarify your folder settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help.

```
(IF /I "%~dp2"=="G:\TV Shows\" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\theRenamer\theRenamer.exe" -fetch))
```

Comment: Thank that worked a treat. Would you mind telling me what the "%~dp2" line does?

Comment: `for /?` at the end of the help shows the modifiers.  %~dp takes the drive letter and path from the 2nd command parameter in this case.  %~nx2 will show the filename and extension of the same paramter.